# jquery ajax popup and return selected checkbox inside pop up form

Tags: forms, jquery

Seems like a common question but could not find on this site. Must be due to my lack of experience in jquery or ajax.

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="form1">
<a href="add-item.php">+Add Item</a>
</form>
```

when the person clicks "+Add Item" it pops up a new page which allows him to navigate and click the desired checkbox. Then it should insert in the above form something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item1_id" value="4">Item 1<br>
```

where value="4" would be the id of the checkbox checked.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an anchor tag. Instead, create a div `container` for your pop up, which you can [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) dynamically:

```
$('#container').load('add-item.php');
```

Then add a listener to your item buttons append the result in your form:

```
$("#item_1").click(function() {
    var $newinput = $("<input type='hidden' />");
    $newinput.val(4);
    $newinput.attr("name","item1_id")
    $("#form1").append($newinput,"Item 1<br>");
});
```

Comment: thanks but can the add-item.php file return some kind of popup to select something? and whatever is selected goes into the container?

Comment: imagine that `add-item.php` returns the _content_ for a popup, but that the popup itself is just an overlaid `div` with a high `z-index`. check out this simple example: http://istockphp.com/demo/popup-div-with-jquery/